# Why does calculating my enemy's movement doesnt make it move in that direction?

Tags: python

I have a game, where there is an enemy and its ai only moves it northwest. It should move in all directions, but it doesnt and i cant figure it out. Can someone help me?
The enemy code:

```py
import pygame
import inventory_essentials
import variables
import level
import os
import projectiles
import math
import random


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, type, damage=50, health=100):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = type
        self.pos = pos
        self.damage = damage
        self.state_stage = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.health = health
        self.fireballs = []
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(pos[0] + 10, pos[1] + 10))
        self.fireballs = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def update(self, x_shift, do_damage=False):
        self.ai()
        self.rect.x += x_shift
        self.rect.x += math.cos(self.direction)
        self.rect.y += math.sin(self.direction)
        if random.randint(0, 100) > 99:
            destination = pygame.math.Vector2(variables.current_coords[0] - self.rect.x, variables.current_coords[1] - self.rect.y)
            destination.normalize()
            destination.scale_to_length(10)
            new_fireball = projectiles.Fireball((self.rect.x + 10, self.rect.y + 10), variables.fireball_icon, self.damage, destination)
            variables.level.create_fireball(new_fireball)

    def ai(self):
        dd = random.randint(-int(math.pi/2)*100, int(math.pi/2)*100)/100
        self.direction += dd
        print(math.cos(self.direction), math.sin(self.direction))
        pass
```

i have calculated the sin and cos for the movement and it still doesnt work. Any help is appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

I do not speak python but one thing stands out at me anyway:

int(math.pi/2)

I am not sure what you are trying to do with this line but I'm sure you're not getting the expected result.  That's going to evaluate to 1.

Comment: the randint function requires ints, not floats, thats why

Comment: @QUACK I figured that was probably what was going on but that doesn't change the fact that you can't simply write something that compiles and expect to get the right output.

Comment: i know, i just wanted it to work :(

Comment: @QUACK One bit of advice:  That statement is too complex for a novice.  Break it up so you have actual variables for the intermediate values, it makes things much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to generate the range `[-pi/2, pi/2]` with your line `dd = random.randint(-int(math.pi/2)*100, int(math.pi/2)*100)/100`, however because you are casting to int, you are only getting range `[-1, 1]`

Try doing something like this:
`dd = random.random() * math.pi - math.pi/2`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to move the enemy randomly in a circle with  max radius of 100 units.
I would use two random values; first one random radius between -100, +100
second one is random angle as  radiant  you can choose it between 0 and 360 degrees or as radiants [0, 2pi]

there we go

```
import random
import math


random_raduis = random.randint(-100, +100)
random_angles_in_degrees = random.randint(0, 360)
random_angles_in_radians = math.radians(random_angles_in_degrees)
enemy_new_x_coordinates = math.cos(random_angles_in_radians) * random_raduis
enemy_new_y_coordinates = math.sin(random_angles_in_radians) * random_raduis
```